# API-Platform, wrap response body in a parent object

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

We have an URL like `GET /users` and currently we receive data using API-Platform, Symfony and Doctrine like this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "jane"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "john"
  },
]
```

Now we need to wrap this response into a parent object `users` like

```json
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "jane"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "firstName": "john"
    },
  ]
}
```

The question is how to achive this using API-Platform?

Comment: Easiest way is to use a custom controller and return the data as an array `[users => $users]`.  https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#alternative-method

Comment: @CodeSpirit That's true, but we don't like to use a controller as their usage is discouraged by the docs: "Note: using custom controllers with API Platform is discouraged. Also, GraphQL is not supported"

Comment: Discouraged but not forbidden. Another solution would be to create a EventListener which listens to [`kernel.view`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-view) event and sets the data accordingly but it will run for all controllers and not just users. Thats why I suggested to use a custom controller because you only want to change this route and I do not see any other feature of API Platform that supports this.
Also you can just convert the data on the frontend without changing the API and just leave it as is.

Comment: I think you can use Smth like `UsersDTO` and use `output=UsersDTO::class` attribute in `collectionOperations:get` operation. https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/ for the reference.

Comment: @EugeneRuban No, the DTO will interact with the elements of the collection, not the collection itself.

Comment: @CodeSpirit We like to use this pattern in all responses. So for a `GET /posts` we expect a response like `{"posts": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]}`. All responses should be wraped in some kind of parent element. We will give `kernel.view` a try.

Comment: @halanson Which is not "the same" because they keys change (users, posts) etc.
So to make this work in a single class/implementation you have to add custom attributes / extend api platform attributes to inject metadata. So I guess using custom controller would be easier. Also I think you only want to apply this to GET request responses?

Answer (score 0):

For override the APIPLATFORM serialization proccess and incorporate your own logic, you need to create a custom opération with your own controller. Define a custom operation in your Entity and create the controller.

```
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [  'get' => [
            'pagination_enabeld' => true,
            'method' => 'get',
            'controller' => getUsersController::class,
            'read' => false,
        ]]
```

Now in your controller you can define your own logic and return a json response

```
class getUsersController extends AbstractController {

    // get all users and push each of them in array named users
    // json encode and return the response 
    // dont forget exeption and errors cases
}
```

Dont forgot indicate the responses details in response attributes of openapicontext for swaggerui

[You can use APIPLATFORM opérations documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#configuring-operations)